# Why my parameters are not getting passed to the RESTful web service?

Tags: java, angular, rest

I have this code using Angular 4 `HttpClient`, supposed to communicate with a simple RESTful JAVA web service and get a `JSON`string back:

```
this.client.post('http://localhost:8080/ToDoService/rest/service/create', {id: 'foo', todo: 'bar'}).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("Got data: ", data);
}, (error) => {
    console.log("Error", error);           
})
```

It's not working. What I mean is that the `id` and `todo` parameters are not getting passed to the REST backend.

At the other hand, if I change above code to:

```
this.client.post('http://localhost:8080/ToDoService/rest/service/create?id=foo&todo=bar', '').subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("Got data: ", data);
}, (error) => {
    console.log("Error", error);           
})
```

Everything works fine, but I'm sure the second snipped is wrong. It just looks wrong.

Could you give me a push and point my mistake?

P.s

The `JAVA` backend:

```
@Path("/service")
public class Rest extends Application{
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
        public Response printMessage(@QueryParam("id") String userId, @QueryParam("todo") String toDo) {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

            result.put("id", userId);
            result.put("todo", toDo);

            return Response.status(200).entity(result.toString()).build();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're mapping QueryParams, you need to map that payload to either a Map or an Object:**

```
class PayLoad {
    private String id;
    private String todo;
    // Getter and Setters
}

@Path("/service")
public class Rest extends Application{
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
        public Response printMessage(@RequestBody PayLoad payload) {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

            result.put("id", payload.getId());
            result.put("todo", payload.getTodo());

            return Response.status(200).entity(result.toString()).build();
        }
}
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Nope, it's not getting sent.

Comment: `@Path` and `@POST` are from JAX-RS. `@RequestBody` is from Spring MVC. They must not be mixed and `@RequestBody` has no effect here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, looking at the [MyKong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/) you can see that `@QueryParam` accepts parameters sent **in the URL**. That is a first problem here. Back to the main point.

---

I am not an expert in Angular 4, but I think the problem lies deeper in your architecture. You are sending to your backend:

`{id: 'foo', todo: 'bar'}`

and expect in your Java:

`@QueryParam("id") String userId, @QueryParam("todo") String toDo`

You pass **an object** and expect in your Java backend **two strings**. If you want to get your object, you might create this kind of class:

```
public class JsonWrapper    {
    private String id;
    private String todo;

 // Classic constructor and setters
}
```

Then, in your service:

```
@Path("/service")
public class Rest extends Application    {
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    public Response printMessage(@RequestBody JsonWrapper wrapper) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        result.put("id", wrapper.getId());
        result.put("todo", wrapper.getTodo());

        return Response.status(200).entity(result.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

If the `JsonWrapper` does not work, I think a `Map` can do the trick, too.